# Modify through arithmetic operations floating point numbers (positive and negative) in a file

Tags: shell, if-statement, floating-point, numbers

I have a file listed like this:

```
-180.0564
-179.0857
178.4739
```

I need to look through the whole file and change only the positive (or negative) values subtracting an integer like 100 or in my case 360.
I develop this code looking in the web and I'm using the `bc` command for the floating operations.

The problem is that is changing now all the negative values instead of the positive ones and I cannot understand why.

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1

while read line;do

 if [ $(echo $line '>' 0.0 |bc -l) ]; then

    line=$(echo "$line-360" |bc)
    echo $line

    else

    echo $line
fi

done < $FILE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any task involving processing lines, it's worth considering using awk:

```
awk '{ print ($0 > 0 ? $0 - 360 : $0) }' "$file"
```

This code replaces your entire `while read` loop. In awk, `$0` refers to the contents of each line. The logic is the same as in your code: if the line is greater than 0, then subtract 360, otherwise leave it as it is.

A shorter way of writing the same thing using awk would be this:

```
awk '$0 > 0 { $0 -= 360 }1' "$file"
```

The structure of an awk program is `condition { action }`, so the logic is the same as above. This version uses the common shorthand `1` which is the shortest condition that's always true. The default action is `{ print }`, which prints the whole line.

Either one of these options will be quicker, as they don't call external processes and because awk is faster than `while read` anyway. More importantly, they are also shorter and easier to read.

Note that I'm using `$file` rather than `$FILE`, as uppercase variable names should generally be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the script, I do also think that awk is easier but I still got this error
`awk: linea com.:1: { print line > 0 ? line - 360 : line }
awk: linea com.:1:                  ^ syntax error
awk: linea com.:1: { print line > 0 ? line - 360 : line }
awk: linea com.:1:                               ^ syntax error`

I'm launching directly the line putting my file name at the end instead of "$FILE" is it correct like this?

Comment: Sorry, my code was completely wrong! I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user2710445 yes you can call awk passing a file name directly from an interactive shell, no need for a variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now is working. 
Just I didn't understand the 1 but after a quick search I understood that it stands for { print $0 }. I think awk is so powerful thanks to all this shorthand, definitely I need to study it more.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `[]` (actually program `test`) is designed to test *returncode* - zero if a program ends successfully.

```
$ [ 0 ] && echo ok || echo err
ok
```

As for your computations, I would get rid of one `bc` call with *modulo*.

```
$ while read line; do bc <<< "($line-360)%360"; done < $FILE
-180.0564
-179.0857
-181.5261
```